# Check if all required DLLs and their dependencies exist on target

Tags: c#

Is there a good way in C# to check if all referenced DLLs are installed on the target machine?

What I want to achieve is that my software doesn't start if one of the referenced DLLs are missing on the target machine. Based on that I can be sure that my features won't break during runtime because a DLL can't be found.

My idea: Create a separate AppDomain during startup, and load ALL referenced DLLs to it. If it fails I'd shut down my software. If loading succeeds I'd unload the separate AppDomain and proceed to start the software. Is it a good idea to perform the check in such a manner, or are there some known problems/pitfalls around it.

I'm aware that I posted no corresponding piece of code, I only want to gather feedback if my idea is a good one or not.

Thx

Comment: Your software doesn't start anyway when the referenced assembly is missing. You can have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading) articles to see how the assembly resolution works. You can also try the reflection-only load